# Elastic Cloud PHP Connection error: I did not find any HTTP library with HttpAsyncClient interface

Tags: elasticsearch, httpclient, guzzle

When connecting to Elastic Cloud Im constantly running into this weird error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Elastic\Transport\Exception\NoAsyncClientException: I did not find any HTTP library with HttpAsyncClient interface. Make sure to install a package providing "php-http/async-client-implementation". You can also set a specific async library using Elastic\Transport\Transport::setAsyncClient()

I have tried everything the internet offers in terms of setting http clients, composer Guzzle etc... But to no avail. I also tested it on one of our live servers and the error is there too.

**My code**:

```
$httpClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHttpClient($httpClient)
    ->setElasticCloudId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    ->setBasicAuthentication('xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    ->build();
```

**Composer**

```
{
"require": {
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^8.6",
    "php-http/async-client-implementation": "*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.5"
},
"config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
        "php-http/discovery": true
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`disclaimer: I'm not a php dev either`

You should require a concrete asynch adapter/implementation for those client libraries that are not [PSR-18 compliant](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-18/), like

```
"require": {
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^8.6",
    "php-http/async-client-implementation": "*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.5",
    "php-http/guzzle7-adapter": "*"            <----------
}
```

Comment: Yes! This solved it, thanks man. It all seems so logical now!

Comment: Anything else needed?

Comment: No man thanks! I can, and will, reward in three hours :)

Answer (score 0):

`disclaimer: I'm not a php dev`,

but, according to the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/http-client.html#_configuring_the_http_async_client),

> You can enable the HTTP async in elasticsearch-php using the setAsync() function

Comment: I tried this, but it makes no difference unfortunately. Also tried setting it to false. The error actually shows when I build the client so it never gets to the async function.